# When exactly ModelSerializer saves data to model?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this model and serializer:

```
class User(Model):
    name = Charfield()
    is_available = BooleanField()

class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

And I also have this view function:

```
@api_view('GET', 'PATCH')
def current_user(request):
    serializer = UserSerializer(request.user, context={'request': request})
    if request.method == 'PATCH':
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

PATCH request returns 200 OK, but doesn't change user data. It looks like calling serializer.save() is not enough to save the data to model. So when exactly ModelSerializer saves data to model?

Comment: It saves it when you call `save()`, not surprisingly. If the data is not being saved, that is presumably because `serializer.is_valid()` is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update object you should pass it's instance to serializer as first argument, otherwise serializer will create new object. Also you need to add `partial=True` to allow partial updates, without it all required fields (not only actual updating) should be provided to update user. Change code to this:

```
if request.method == 'PATCH':
    user = request.user
    serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.data, partial=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
```